# Using SelectMany() or matching elements of two sequences with LINQ (dot syntax)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I need select all elements from a set whose Id property is contained within a second set. Can "SelectMany()" be used to accomplish this? What is the most efficient / best solution for this type of matching problem.

**Example**:
Select all DateRangeIds for a given ReportId by way of a joining entity set.

**Sets**:

- **Reports** {ReportId, ReportName}
- **ReportDateRanges** {DateRangeId, ReportId, ReportDateRangeId}
- **DateRanges** {DateRangeId, DateRangeName}

Here is my solution's code. I am unsure if this is the proper approach, but this does solve the problem I've described:

```
    var report = Reports.Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
    int reportId = Convert.ToInt32(report.Id);
    var dateRangeIds = ReportDateRanges.Where(rdr => rdr.ReportId == reportId).OrderBy(it => it.DateRangeId).Select(it => it.DateRangeId);
    var dateRanges = DateRanges.Where(dateRange => dateRangeIds.Contains(dateRange.Id));
```

LINQ experts, please feel free to critique this code and offer any suggestions. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use an [Enumerable.Intersect(Of TSource) Method (IEnumerable(Of TSource), IEnumerable(Of TSource), IEqualityComparer(Of TSource))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408.aspx)

for example:

```
var list1 = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
var list2 = new List<int> {9,10,11,12,13,4,5};
list1.Intersect(list2);
```

result

```
4,5
```

Using overload specified in link, you can specify `EqualityComparer` for your custom object in order to find intersection of both enumerations.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is simple and readable but there are something which is not good:

```
var report = Reports.Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

you can write:

```
var report = Reports.FirstOrDefault();
```

And in this line:

```
var dateRangeIds = ReportDateRanges.Where(rdr => rdr.ReportId == reportId)
                                   .OrderBy(it => it.DateRangeId)
                                   .Select(it => it.DateRangeId);
```

you used orderby but you don't need this.

Answer (score 1):

You can join the collections.
Given that you have the `reportId` you can issue this query.

```
Reports
    .Where(report => report.ReportId == reportId)
    .Join(ReportDateRanges, 
              report => report.ReportId, 
              rdr => rdr.ReportId,
              (report, reportDateRange) => reportDateRange)
    .Join(DateRanges,
              rdr => rdr.DateRangeId,
              dateRange => dateRange.DateRangeId,
              (reportDateRange, dateRange) => dateRange);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
IEnumerable<SomeTypeWithAnIDProperty> sourceSequence = //whatever
IEnumerable<TypeOfTheIDProperty> ids = //whatever

var selectedItems = 
    from sourceObject in sourceSequence
    join id in ids
        on sourceObject.ID equals id
    select sourceObject;
```

Or, to use your example

```
var dateRangeIds = ReportDateRanges
    .Where(rdr => rdr.ReportId == reportId)
    .OrderBy(it => it.DateRangeId)
    .Select(it => it.DateRangeId);

var dateRanges = DateRanges.Join(dateRangeIds, dateRange => dateRange.Id, id => id, (dateRange, id) => dateRange);
```